# FYP ideas in Applications of Machine Learning in Cyber Security domain

Tags: antivirus, ids, research, waf, machine-learning

I am a Computer Science Engineering undergraduate aspiring to pursue a career in the field of cyber security. I have some experience in web application security, memory and network forensics fields. I would like to have some suggestions for my FYP in cyber security + Machine learning domain.I have seen some projects such as Network IDS, Malware classification,WAF in above mentioned domain.Since there are so many projects going on those topics already, I am interested to get some different ideas or any specific idea relevant to above sub topics .

Comment: what does FYP mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for ideas for research are off-topic. The list of potential answers is infinite.

Comment: FYP - final year project